# How to know if there are still hidden hidden files after revealing them without root?

Tags: adb, root-access, file-system, hidden, shizuku

I did write *hidden* twice on the title, that means, there were hidden files, and I managed to reveal all of them or perhaps some of them using Shizuku and FV File Manager and there might be hidden files that are still hidden.

To illustrate what I'm saying, suppose the folder *com.A* in the directory *0/Android/data/com.A*, originally has 3 folders, namely A, B and C. A non-rooted android user of the app could only see the folder A. In fact, they can see the folder B using Shizuku that grants the user to read and write the folder without rooting the device. However, suppose Shizuku only helps them to read B but not C (Please tell me that my assumption is incorrect), now, how can we be 100% sure if there are no hidden files left?

I ask this question, because default file manager on my android that has "See hidden files" can't show the whole hidden files, but turns out the other file manager can. And I'm thinking about some files that were downloaded but I couldn't find them in my *data* directory. They must be stored somewhere. Also I require some advice without rooting my device if that's even possible. Even if I had to test it on an emulator that has root access, would be fine. Thanks.

Comment: Use adb, and execute the command `ls -al` followed by the name of the directory whose files/directories you want to see. It would show you everything that exists in that directory.